# Updating Models with AWS MultiDataModel in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

When experimenting with Sagemaker I discovered the Multi Model endpoint with Sagemaker to be a good way to serve models with a scalable infrastructure that is relatively easy to setup. However, Sagemaker seems to have a LRU cache that reads the models from S3 iff not loaded. So now my question is: are the models that are - iff overwritten - still read from S3 if they are in the cache but the model version is different or do I need to write a Lambda function and think about a data base to find a work around ?

Answer (score 0):

SageMaker Multi-Model Endpoints(MME) use similar to a LRU cache(with some secret sauce, not precisely the same). So, when you place your models(tar ball) in S3 bucket, based on the memory available of the instance selected, MME loads the models in memory. Now, when you encounter a situation when the model is either newly updated in S3 or not loaded into memory, it dynamically offloads the least used models from memory and loads that model into memory as your rightly pointed out.
Now, to answer your question what happens when on model versions that are loaded in cache, unless you do an "update endpoint operation" or rename the model file in S3, the newer versions of the model are not automatically loaded into the endpoint.